# Safely accessing negative index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it a convention/specification that in Javascript:

If we don't assign anything to a negative index of an array `a`, say index `-1`, then `a[-1]` will always return undefined, and its object keys and length remain unchanged?

Comment: It's a read access. It doesn't mutate state. If we're talking about specifications, ECMAScript spec is freely available online and you're welcome to peruse it. Interesting read.

Comment: Arrays always start from 0 index. So negative index are just nonsense.

Comment: `var a = []; a[-1] = 'foo'; alert(a[-1]);` – "Always" is such a strong word…

Comment: The question still makes no sense.

Comment: @deceze, but `-1` is not a numerical index of an array.

Comment: @deceze now try to loop and log that 'foo'...Your setting property but not the array data.

Comment: @Mykola, Nina Sure, no argument from me on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a convention/specification that [...] `a[-1]` will always return undefined[?]

No, no it's not:

```js
var a = [];
a[-1] = 'foo';
console.log(a[-1]);
```

However, this indeed won't alter the `length` property of the array, because only properties which are integers >= 0 are considered to be part of the array indexes; any other properties you set on the object, including `.foo`, `.bar` and `[-1]`, are not considered an array index.